# Check whether modification in re.sub occurred

Tags: python, python-re

The Python function `re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)` returns the modified string with the matched pattern replaced with the replacement. Is there any easy way to check whether a match has occurred and a modification has been made? (And also, how many modifications)

Comment: If performance is not an issue, you can check to see if the regex does any matches in the string before doing the sub.

Comment: @Patashu That's true. What would be most efficient? (I'm not so familiar with Python regex). Would it be `if re.search(pattern, string) != None`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depends on the version. In Python <= 2.6, you have to couple `sub()` with `match()` or `search()` to get count.

If you are using Python >= 2.7, you can use [`subn()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn), which will return a tuple of `(new_string, number_of_subs_made)`.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.subn('l', 'X', "Hello World!")
('HeXXo WorXd!', 3)
```

Comment: Check that: it subn may have been in prior to 2.7. http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn

Comment: `subn()` is available in 3+ as well.